# How do I copy list to another spreadsheet only if items have been paid?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I have a list of invoices.  I want only the invoices that have been paid to be copied to another worksheet. My column headings are:

```
Inv. # / Date of Inv. / Amount / Customer Name / Date Paid /  Check #
```

What can I use to accomplish that?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you share with us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried Advanced Sort, but it doesn't copy the entire line of data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy the list manually, you can turn on Filter and hide all rows with blank Date Paid. Then you can select all and copy. This will only copy the rows that have something in Date Paid.

Steps:

1. Select all columns in the current sheet
2. Click Data on the menu bar, Filter, AutoFilter
3. Now you should have square dropdown buttons next to each column heading
4. Click the dropdown button at Date Paid
5. Uncheck `(Blanks)`
6. Select all rows that remain (Ctrl+A), and copy them (Ctrl+C)
7. Go to another sheet and paste (Ctrl+V)
8. To remove the AutoFilter, do step 2 again on the original sheet